# How to calculate the time difference in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

How to get the remaining time up to the date of consumption ..

```
{{$item->created_at->toDateString()->diffInDays($item->expired)}}
{{$item->created_at->toDateString() - $item->expired}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a function on a string.

See:

`$item` *Instance of \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model*

`$item->created_at` *Instance of \Carbon\Carbon*

`$item->created_at->toDateString()` *string*

`$item->created_at->toDateString()->diffInDays()` *FatalThrowableError Call 
to a member function diffInDays() on string*

Try:

`{{ $item->created_at->diffInDays($item->expired) }}`

---

After comment:
Your expired attribute is a string and not a date:
Tell Eloquent to mutate it as a date:

```
class Item {
    protected $dates = ['expired'];
}
```

Comment: I have this Error with this way
Argument 1 passed to Carbon\Carbon::diffInDays() must be an instance of Carbon\Carbon, string given

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ $item->created_at->diffInDays($item->expired) }}
```